# ¿cómo unir dos valores para obtener el nombre de una variable/ array/objeto ya declarado en JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, array, string, select, objeto

¿como están?
Tengo un formulario dónde el usuario debe seleccionar el Año y el Mes.
una vez que tengo esa información necesito acceder a un objeto ya declarado cuyo nombre es la concatenación de esos valores (mesAño) para poder realizar unos cálculos.

dejo una muestra simplificada del código, para tratar que se entienda la consulta.

muestra HTML:

```
<label for="anioSelect">Año: </label>
<select name="anioSelect" id="anioSelect">
<label for="mesSelect">Mes: </label>
<select name="mesSelect" id="mesSelect">
```

muestra JavaScript:

```
const selectAnio=document.querySelector("#anioSelect");
const selectMes=document.querySelector("#mesSelect");
let anioElegido=selectAnio.value;
let mesElegido=(selectMes.value).toLowerCase();
let periodoElegido=`${mesElegido}${anioElegido}`;
```

ya que necesito poder consultar estos objetos:

```
class Paritaria {
    constructor(basico, noRemunerativo){
        this.basico=basico;
        this.noRemunerativo=noRemunerativo;
    }
};

const octubre2020 = new Paritaria (41669.63, 5000);
const noviembre2020 = new Paritaria (50000, 6500);
const diciembre2020 = new Paritaria (65000, 7250);
```

para poder usar los valores  para realizar calculos:

```
function calcularSueldo(periodoElegido){
    let sueldo= periodoElegido.basico*1.1+periodoElegido.noRemunerativo;
    return sueldo;
}
```

el tema es que periodoElegido.basico es undefined, porque claro, periodoElegido almacena un dato tipo string que no tiene ninguna vinculación con el objeto que necesito consultar

Comment: Presta atención a la ortografía, es lo primero que la gente ve, puedes ser el mejor informático del mundo pero si no das una buena impresión de primeras es muy difícil que tomen en serio tus preguntas :). Después, todavía no entiendo que relación tienen 'Año' y 'Mes' con el objeto 'Paritaria' y la función 'calcularSueldo', tu pregunta no se entienda y esta incompleta, saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Un par de cosas:

Como bien comentas, la variable periodoElegido es de tipo string, por lo que no puedes acceder a periodoElegido.basico.

Mientras que octubre2020, noviembre2020, diciembre2020 son de tipo Paritaria. Estos si tienen esa propiedad o field.

No sé si puedes acceder a ellas de alguna manera directamente solo sabiendo el nombre. Pero se me ocurre que puedes almacenarlos en un objeto y acceder con su nombre de la siguiente forma:

```
const paritarias = {
  octubre2020,
  noviembre2020,
  diciembre2020
}

paritarias[periodoElegido] // esto es como si hicieras paritarias["noviembre2020"]
```

y acceder a sus propiedades

```
paritarias[periodoElegido].basico
```

No tienes por qué hacerlo así pero sabiendo esto te puede servir para organizar tu código de forma que puedas hacer uso de eso y lograr lo que quieres. Seguro hay otras formas de hacerlo pero fue la que se me vino a la mente.

Espero te sirva.

Comment: muchas gracias!!!

Comment: De nada, si te ha servido de algo puedes ayudarme votando ;)